# How to use JNA callback

Tags: java, callback, jna

I am using JNA to call functions of a dll file.

simpleDLL.h:

```
typedef int (__stdcall *eventCallback)(unsigned int id, int value);

namespace test
{
   class hotas
   {
   public:
   static __declspec(dllexport) int readValue(int a);
   static __declspec(dllexport) void setCallback(eventCallback evnHnd);
   };
}
```

simpleDLL.cpp:

```
#include "simpleDLL.h"
#include <stdexcept>
using namespace std;

namespace test
{
    eventCallback callback1 = NULL;
int test::readValue(int a)
{
    return 2*a;
}

void test::setCallback(eventCallback evnHnd)
{
    callback1 = evnHnd;
}  
}
```

My Java Interface looks like this:

```
public interface DLLMapping extends Library{

DLLMapping INSTANCE = (DLLMapping) Native.loadLibrary("simpleDLL", DLLMapping.class);

int readValue(int a);

public interface eventCallback extends Callback {

    boolean callback(int id, int value);
}

public void setCallback(eventCallback evnHnd);
}
```

And finally the java main:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    DLLMapping sdll = DLLMapping.INSTANCE;

    int a = 3;
    int result = sdll.readValue(a);
    System.out.println("Result: " + result);

    sdll.setCallback(new eventCallback(){
        public boolean callback(int id, int value) {
            //System.out.println("bla");
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

My problem is that I got the error, that java cannot find the function setCallback.
What's wrong on my code?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Note that `eventCallback` in C++ is declared as `__stdcall`, so the `eventCallback` interface in Java should be extending JNA's `StdCallLibrary.StdCallCallback` interface instead of the `Callback` interface directly. Also, `eventCallback` in C++ returns an `int`, so `eventCalllback.callback()` in Java should be returning `int` instead of `boolean`.

Answer (score 5):

C++ is not the same thing as C.  Dump the symbols from your DLL (http://dependencywalker.com), and you will see that the function name (at least from the linker's point of view) is not "setCallback".

Use `extern "C"` to avoid name mangling on exported functions, rename your Java function to match the exported linker symbol, or use a FunctionMapper to map the Java method name to the linker symbol.