# Java Native Access and delphi

Tags: java, delphi

I am writing code in java which calling delphi dll.
to invoke the delphi dll I am usig JNA and its work great.
My problem is when events are being called in the delphi and I need to invoke java code.
is this possible in JNA?

Comment: You might find the following link to be of some use : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501194/loading-a-delphi-dll-in-java-using-jna

Comment: I have alraedy saw this post, this post talk about invoke delphi functions from java, and I need to invoke java code from delphi, and I Know there is the JNI, but I hope that JNA can do that too

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As discussed on the related thread ([loading a delphi dll in java using jna](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16501194/loading-a-delphi-dll-in-java-using-jna)), the flow is:

- create dll in delphi
- create a delphi or c++ app that can load the dll and successfully call the funcs in it
  --- do not proceed until this is done!
- now load dll from JNA

The interesting part for your project is that you want the delphi code to invoke java code.

I can think of only two ways to achieve the delphi --> java flow:

- Implement a callback on the java side, so the delphi code can pump java code when needed ([How to use JNA callback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11849595/how-to-use-jna-callback))
- Have the delphi dll start a thread (that is bad, better: in java start a thread which loads a delphi dll func that runs) and use a different kind of IPC for the delphi code to pump java code (via a socket, shared memory, or other technique)