# how to work implement JNA callback?

Tags: java, jna

I am developing a web application using jsf, spring and hibernate. This application is 
similar to other web sites like `money.rediff.com` and `finance.yahoo.com`. Our company has 
made a deal with a realtime data provider. He provided a `exe file` 
which on installing generates a `dll file`, pdf listing the methods of dll file and other 
license documents.

I used dependency walker and found that the methods are decorated with some symbols. I
am trying to call the methods of dll file with the help of JNA in the following way.

Here are my codes,

**DllImplementation .java**

```
public interface CLibrary extends StdCallLibrary
    {
       CLibrary INSTANCE = (CLibrary) Native.loadLibrary("DeskApi", CLibrary.class, new 

HashMap() {{

              put("Initialise", "?

Initialise@CDeskApi@@QAEHPADPAVCDeskApiCallback@@@Z");
              put("GetQuote","?GetQuote@CDeskApi@@QAEHPADHKK@Z");
              put("DeleteQuote","?DeleteQuote@CDeskApi@@QAEHPADH@Z");
              put("VersionInfo","?VersionInfo@CDeskApi@@QAEHPAD@Z");

              //Other functions
              }});

    public int Initialise(String serialkey,CDeskApiCallback callBack);
    public int GetQuote(String symbol, int periodicity, long lasttimeupdate, long 

echo);
    public int DeleteQuote(String symbol, int periodicity);
    public int VersionInfo(String versionOut);

    }




    public static  void main(String argv[]) {

            try{

                CDeskApiCallback callback = new CDeskApiCallback();

                String key = "fsg@xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxd24";

                int retValue = CLibrary.INSTANCE.Initialise(key,callback);

                System.out.println("Initialise () ="+retValue);  




             } catch (UnsatisfiedLinkError e) {

                 e.printStackTrace();
             }
        }
}
```

**CDeskApiCallback.java**

```
public class CDeskApiCallback {


    public  native int realtime_notify(String symbol, Pointer recent);
    public  native int quote_notify( String symbol, int interval, int nMaxSize, 

    Pointer quotes, long echo);

}
```

**Quotation.java**

```
public class Quotation  extends Structure implements Structure.ByReference{ 
    public NativeLong DateTime; // 8 byte
    public float   Price;
    public float   Open;
    public float   High;
    public float   Low;
    public float   Volume;
    public float   OpenInterest;

    public Quotation(){
       super();
       System.out.println("in Quotation()");
       read();
    }

}
```

**RecentInfo.java**

```
public class RecentInfo extends Structure  implements Structure.ByReference{

    public  float   fOpen;
    public  float   fHigh;
    public  float   fLow;
    public  float   fLast;
    public  float   fTradeVol;
    public  float   fTotalVol;
    public  float   fOpenInt;
    public  float   fPrev;
    public  float   fBid;
    public  float   fAsk;
    public  int     iBidSize;   
    public  int     iAskSize;
    public  NativeLong  DateTime;

    public RecentInfo(){
        super();
        read();
        }

}
```

To test the code when I execute the main method I am getting a -1 as a integer return value. From the pdf of software providers it indicates as an error. How can i implement the callback mechanism.

I am new to JNA feature . Any clue or help will be highly appreciable.

---

**Edit:**

@manuell

First of all thanks for the help. I made the changes as advised but no use. I am pasting the header file given by the software provider. Please suggest...

```
#pragma once
//version 0.0 Beta 1
#define DAILY_PERIOD 24*60
#define MIN_PERIOD   1

#ifdef API_DLL 
#define METHOD_TYPE __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define METHOD_TYPE __declspec(dllimport)
#endif
//data is provided in the struct below
struct Quotation {
                        unsigned long DateTime; // 8 byte
                        float   Price;
                        float   Open;
                        float   High;
                        float   Low;
                        float   Volume;
                        float   OpenInterest;                       
                 };

struct RecentInfo
{
    float   fOpen;
    float   fHigh;
    float   fLow;
    float   fLast;
    float   fTradeVol;
    float   fTotalVol;
    float   fOpenInt;
    float   fPrev;
    float   fBid;
    int     iBidSize;
    float   fAsk;
    int     iAskSize;
    unsigned long DateTime; // 8 byte   
};

//callback class which is to be implemented by the client application
class METHOD_TYPE CDeskApiCallback
{
    public:
        /*
        Description : Tick Update from the server for symbol requested
        Parameters  : 1. symbol of interest
                      2. Data, please note value -1 indicates no update.
        Return      : 0 in case of success and -1 in case of error  
        */  
    virtual int realtime_notify(const char* symbol, RecentInfo *pRecent)=0;
        /*
        Description : Vwap Update from the server for symbol requested
        Parameters  : 1. symbol of interest
                      2. update of interval requested
                      3. data size
                      4. data
                      5. user message
        Return      : 0 in case of success and -1 in case of error  
        */  
    virtual int quote_notify( const char* symbol, int interval, int nMaxSize, Quotation *pQuotes, unsigned long echo)=0;    
};

//this is the control class from which requests are initiated.
class  METHOD_TYPE CDeskApi
{
public:
    CDeskApi(void);

        /*
    Description : Initiates a connection to NEST system
    Parameters  : 1. serialkey provided to implement the api
                  2. object of CDeskApiCallback implemented

    Return      : 0 in case of success and -1 in case of error  
        */  
    int Initialise(char *serialkey, CDeskApiCallback* callback);
        /*
        Description : Request data from the server
        Parameters  : 1. symbol of interest
                      2. intervals of 1 min, multiples of 1 min, DAILY_PERIOD in case of daily.
                      3. data to be retrieved from. in no of seconds since epoch
                      4. identifier, which is returned in the callback          
        Return      : 0 in case of success and -1 in case of error  
        */  

    int GetQuote(char * symbol, int periodicity, unsigned long lasttimeupdate, unsigned long echo);
        /*
        Description : Delete a Prior Request to the server
        Parameters  : 1. symbol of interest
                      2. interval, send -1 to delete all requested information of the symbol 
        Return      : 0 in case of success and -1 in case of error  
        */  
    int DeleteQuote(char * symbol, int periodicity);
        /*
        Description : Delete a Prior Request to the server
        Parameters  : 1. symbol of interest
                      2. interval, send -1 to delete all requested information of the symbol 
        Return      : 0 in case of success and -1 in case of error  
        */  
    int VersionInfo(char * versionout);
    ~CDeskApi(void);
};
```

Comment: You can't just pass a Java `String` to a C/C++ function. and your callbacks should inherit from `Callback`. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/10158582/1374704 and http://stackoverflow.com/q/11849595/1374704

Comment: I have edited my question, please have a look at it.

Comment: I am not fluent in JNA. It appears that you can indeed use the Java String class to call a native function expecting a C char* argument. Sorry for telling you otherwise.

Answer (score 2):

The native DLL is a C++ one, exporting classes.

That means, for example, that the Initialise method is a "`*this`" method.

That also means that the callback argument (second one from Initialize) should be a pointer to a `VTBL` (as the C++ `CDeskApiCallback` class is an abstract one).

You may be able to deals with the two problems using the Java `Pointer` type, but that will be tricky hacks. By default, the rules are clear: you can't use JNA in a C++ classes context.

You are left with 3 choices (plus the tricky one):

1. try to use [Bridj](http://code.google.com/p/bridj/)
2. try to use [jnaerator](http://code.google.com/p/jnaerator/)
3. write yourself a C++ Dll Wrapper and use it from JNA (or JNI).

The third one involves basic C/C++ knowledge and a Visual Studio (Express) environnement.